# Evaluation of the normal of the difference of unitarily equivalent projections

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct  projections in a von Neumann algebra $M$. If $\|p-q\|＜1$, then there exits a unitary $u$ such that $q=upu^*$ and $\|1-u\|＜\sqrt{2}\|p-q\|$.

If we only know that $p$ is unitarily equivalent to $q$, can we deduce that there exits a unitary $u$ such that $q=upu^*$ and $\|1-u\|＜\sqrt{2}\|p-q\|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
p=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad q=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad
u=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $upu^*=q$, and
$$
\|1-u\|=2>\sqrt2=\sqrt2\,\|p-q\|.
$$
Any other unitary with $upu^*=q$ is of the form
$$
v=\begin{bmatrix}0&b\\c&0\end{bmatrix},
$$
with $|b|=|c|=1$. Then
$$
\|1-v\|=\Bigg\|\begin{bmatrix}1&-b\\-c&1\end{bmatrix}\Bigg\|\geq\sqrt2.
$$